# Created process template workitem types are not set as inherited

Tags: c#, azure-devops, azure-rm-template

I have created process template from available ADO [API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/processes/processes/create?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1&tabs=HTTP).
Created template is marked as Inherited but its auto created workitem types and not marked as inherited all are system, so I can't modify those work item types.

How can I mark all auto created as inherited at the time of creating process template mention API?

Answer (score 0):

I tested The API [Processes Create](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/processes/processes/create?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1&tabs=HTTP) based on Azure DevOps Services Version Dev19.

The work items types are created automatically when creating process template via API. I can see `edit` menu when you click ellipsis.

If you can’t see the `edit`  menu, please provide your service or server version for further analyzing possible causes.

[image: edit menu in UI]

You can see it’s system from the reference name `Microsoft.VSTS.WorkItemTypes.Bug` but when you  edit the work item type(eg.bug),it will change to inherited work item type  `MyNewAgileProcess.Bug`.

You can use [Processes Get](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/processes/processes/get?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1&tabs=HTTP) to see inherits of work item type.

[image: work item type]

BTW you can also use this API [work item type update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/processes/work-item-types/update?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1&tabs=HTTP) to update your work item types.

Comment: thanks for update. I have created process template again and called the API to get the list of workitem types, it result as system in customization and also inherits as null.
please check [Get workitemtype](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/processes/work-item-types/list?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1&tabs=HTTP)

Comment: @vam I mean the work item types are automatically created as system default type when you invoke the API. In initialization, the inherits is null .But it'll change when you modify or edit them in UI or API. You'd check your UI and make sure whether to see `edit` menu.

Comment: I can see edit button in UI, But when I ty to update workitemtype using API, then it raised the exception, You can not edit system workitem type. can you please verify at your end also?

Comment: yes, I've verified and the same error raised. The system work item type can't be modified by API but worked fine on work items type with inheritance .You should edit in UI firstly and you'll find it has become inherit type. Then you can use API to update.

Comment: I think, Api should always always to update the workitem type of inherit process.

Comment: MS takes security policy into account when designing APIs, and modifications are not allowed for system-level instances. I'm afraid you can only update inherit WITs by this API. You could access [this url](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/AzureDevOps/suggest?space=21) to submit any comments and proposals for future releases and implementations.